# Spring Data JPA Query Validation At Application Start Up

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Data JPA in one of projects and I got below run time exception while deploying the application.

**Tech Stack Is Below :**

Spring Boot 1

Tomcat 8

Spring Data JPA

**Exception :**

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for
>   query for method public abstract java.util.List 
>   com.atul.persistent.dao.ProductDao.findAllSubscribedProductsByUserId(java.lang.Long)!
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:92)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: products of:
>   com.atul.persistent.model.User [select distinct u.products from
>   com.atul.persistent.model.User u join u.products where u.userId =
>   :userId

I already know the reason for this exception as 
I changed JPA entity mapping but forgot to change the query so error is correctly describing the problem.

Below is the wrong query and Correct Query :

```
@Query("select distinct u.products from User u join u.products where u.userId = :userId")
public List<Products> findAllSubscribedProductsByUserId(@Param("userId") Long userId);


@Query("select distinct p from Products p join p.users  where p.users.userId = :userId")
public List<Products> findAllSubscribedProductsByUserId(@Param("userId") Long userId);
```

My question is  :

1) Does Spring Data JPA validates the queries at runtime while application start up ?

2) Since I don't think that this feature is provided by JPA or hibernate , is it provided by Spring Data JPA ?

3) Is it not result in  slow application start up if all queries are validated like this ?

Comment: 1. yes, 2. yes, 3. define slow... Would you rather have the application blow up when you are live and suddenly it comes crashing down on you.

Comment: I agree , but if my application is huge containing hundreds of queries , each query needs to be scanned adding application start up time.My point is , do we have an option to disable this validation , since spring follows is opinionated system design philosophy

Comment: No. There isn't as this is initiated from constructing the `SimpleJpaQuery` class. But again define slow, we have such an application and it isn't really slow...

Comment: I haven't worked on any real world project with Spring Data JPA . What I was suspecting is , query scanning means the objects graph also need to be tracked/scanned for every query  which may result in slow application start up